# vertical align a button- strange behavior

Tags: html, css

I am facing the following weird situation:
I have created a button inside a div and I want it to vertically align in the middle.
Now, when I run the all script, the button remain fixed on top of the div, no matter what method I use (I have tried almost everything). 
If I run it alone (meaning only the related lines of script) then it works and align in the middle. Below I are the lines:

```
<head>
<style>
.p1 {
position: absolute;
left: 250px;
top: 200px;
width: 400px;

background-color: #DFD7D7;
display: block;
height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.p2 {
position: absolute;
left: 250px;
top: 200px;
width: 400px;

background-color: #DFD7D7;
display: none;
height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.bt {
position: absolute;
left: 650px;
top: 200px;
width: 100px;
background-color: #DFD7D7;
height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id1,id2) {
if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='Show Layer'){
document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer';
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';
}
}
</script>
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<%
p_company = Request.form("p_company")
p_email = Request.form("p_email")
p_phone = Request.form("p_phone")
p_type = Request.form("p_type")
p_pword = Request.form("p_pword")
p_pass2 = Request.form("p_pass2")
%>
<%
Session("Language")=Request.querystring("id")
if Session("Language")="ENG" then
%>
<div class="p1" id="sub3">
Company: <%= p_company %>
</div>
<div class="p2" id="sub4">Company:<input type="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="bt">
<input type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub3','sub4');";>
</div>
<%
end if
%>`
```

As you can see I am using line-height for all div and it works fine but not with the button. But (weird) if I separate in another page the code for the button then it works fine too.
Any suggestions
Thank you very much in advance.
Cheers
Valter

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bt">
<input type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('sub3','sub4');";>
</div>
```

You have added no style for bt1, you'll need to assign a margin. So that the child button can be positioned inside the container '#bt'

So add this css:

```
#bt1 {width:40%;
      height:20%;
      margin-top:40%;
      padding:0;}
```

Comment: It's `#bt1` in your css

Comment: Thank you!! Sadly it doesn.t work. It is making me crazy; if I take only the script for the button (html and css) it works nicely, I have also changed the height in div "bt" and still the button goes right in the middle of the div.

Comment: Latest update! After trying almost everything possible, I found out that it works using margin-top only. It does not recognize vertical-align and the two together are going in conflict (i guess since they don't work)